# How to remove trailing newline at end of loop/eof in a Jinja template?

Tags: python, templates, jinja2, newline

I have a simple Jinja template that generates a markdown list which is at the end of the file, e.g.:

```
{% for item in items %}
* Some markdown with the {{ item }}
{% endfor %}
```

The issue is that the resulting file contains 2 newlines at the end. I'm using `trim_blocks` and `lstrip_blocks` options, but that doesn't seem to remove the extra trailing newline:

```
env = Environment(
    loader=FileSystemLoader(templates_dir),
    autoescape=select_autoescape(['md']),
    trim_blocks=True,
    lstrip_blocks=True,
)
```

What else can I try?

Comment: I think Jinja whitespace control will solve your problem: https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/templates/#whitespace-control

Comment: @voscausa Well, apparently not, as I'm already using the two options suggested there (`trim_blocks` and `lstrip_blocks`). It's documented that the entire block line would be removed, but that's not what happens (it leaves 2 newlines at the end of file)

Comment: I never used the trim blocks. And always used the manual control method {- Notice the minus sign. Here is some more info about finding and solving jinja whitespace problems: https://ttl255.com/jinja2-tutorial-part-3-whitespace-control/#ws-in-j2

Comment: @voscausa Wow, [J2Live](https://j2live.ttl255.com/) is super helpful. I think I've found the problem. I'm printing to files with `print(content, file=f)` and that adds  extra newlines. Sometimes it's ok (as Jinja strips a single trailing newline by default), but sometimes it's not. Thanks a lot!